# "can't write to batman adv kernel file" while using "batctl p mac-address"

Tags: linux-kernel

I installed batman-adv and batctl on Ubuntu 14.04.1. When I issue the command: `batctl p 00:16:bf:01:68:46` I get this error:

```
Error - can't write to batman adv kernel file '/sys/kernel/debug//batman_adv/bat0/socket': Invalid argument
```

When I issue this command `ping 192.162.0.182`, I get no errors and it works fine. This MAC address and IP address corresponds to the same host.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your question title is a thing of beauty...

Comment: Did you restarted your system and/or loaded batman module?

Comment: @jasonwryan sadly, the "thing of beauty" was edited out of existence by the Braiam.